# for loop not iterating through my hashmap's key set

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` that is in this format:

```
HashMap<List<String>, List<String[]>>
```

this hashmap is already populated and this is part of the results returned when i view the keyset:

```
[[124, 1], [136, 2], [136, 1], [257, 1], [502A, 1], [269, 1], [111, 1], [232, 1], [123, 1], [93, 1], [81, 1], [93, 2], [6N, 1]]
```

(not full because the whole thing is too long)

I am trying to to a for loop to iterate through all my keyset using this code:

```
for(List<String> key : hashmap.keySet()){
    if(key.get(0) == input){
            if(key.get(1) == "1"/*second part of key*/){
                dir1.add(hashmap.get(key).get(0)[1]);
            }
            else if(key.get(1) == "2"/*second part of key*/){
                dir2.add(hashmap.get(key).get(0)[1]);
            }
        }
}
```

However, when I set a breakpoint and debug the project, I realized that the for loop only loop once. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `//do something` doing? Does it contains a `break`/`return` statement? Do you alter the `hashmap` during execution?

Comment: i am only getting stuff out from the hashmap and my return statement is outside the for loop

Comment: I think it is perhaps advisable to provide the "do something" part (or at least a minimal version of it that reproduces your error). Based on the provided code, there is nothing wrong, but there is not much...

Comment: it would be useful having more details. From what you wrote, it seems all ok

Comment: What can you see in the "key" obj if you put a breakpoint inside the for loop? And is the behaviour of this snippet the expected one?

Comment: the "key" obj returns me 124 and 1 which is the first part of my keyset shown above

Comment: On debug, please hold cursor on hashmap variable and take given data as format {[1, 2]=[[Ljava.lang.String;@57049576]}

Comment: @YusufK. What do u mean?

Comment: `key.get(0) == input` is suspicious to me; it seems to compare Strings by references, rather than contents. Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: I mean, please give us the map's content. not keyset or valueset. Use System.out.println(hashmap) before for

Comment: [124, 1] => [[Ljava.lang.String;@2d0c3619, [Ljava.lang.String;@10bb05e7, [Ljava.lang.String;@1504b0f8, (This is part of it the full one is too long)

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy The keys must be each a list of strings. so `keySet` is `Set<List<String>>` which is then being iterated over

Comment: Did you try to give some output before if(key.get(0) == input){   of course as said before use  if(key.get(0).equals(input)){

Comment: nope. directly after the for loop is the if(key.get(0) == input){

Comment: @TimB ups you´re right, totally overlooked that one..

Comment: While debugging, what is the value of `hashmap.get(key).get(0)[1]`?
Are you sure not having exceptions in the loop?

Comment: @Spock the code does not even reach there beacuse the first if is false

Comment: This confirms what other comments say: use `equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: I've tried that but it does not work as well because the for the input to be equals to the key.get(0), the loop needs to loop a few times first

Answer (score 2):

You should use a proper class for the keys, not `List<String>`

You should compare `Strings` using `.equals.` i.e. `"1".equals(key.get(1))`

The actual `foreach` looks fine so if it isn't looping then either something is breaking/exceptioning you out of the loop or your data structure actually contains only one item. It's also entirely possible it is looping more than once but due to the bad comparisons on the `if` statements you think it isn't.

I'd start by checking your `Map` really contains multiple entries. The way you have it set up at the moment with maps of lists of lists of arrays is just asking for a confusing mess.

Comment: +1 it seems to me, if(key.get(0) == input){ not matching most of values so iterating without action. And a beginner programmer suppose iterates only once etc.

Comment: I've tried commenting out everytinh inside the for loop and it still only loop once. and yes my map does have multiple entries

Comment: @LimJunWei Print out hashMap.size() and hashMap.keySet().size() before entering the loop. What do you get?

Comment: both gives me 496

Comment: And what happens if you put a print statement as the first statement inside the loop just printing the key or something?

Comment: If that doesn't work then all I can suggest is making a SSCE that reproduces the problem and posting it because the symptoms and code you have posted are not compatible. It sounds almost like you've done `for(List<String> key : hashmap.keySet()); {` (see the ; in that line) but that's not in the code above

Answer (score 0):

ok sorry guys the problem is with my netbeans or my computer but i restarted my computer and everything works now. Thanks everyone who tried to help